# Printing python output to txt document

Tags: python

I am having a bit of an issue printing my python output to a txt file. I am currently running a script as such:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob('*.txt')
result = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file,delimiter='  ')
    current_col = df.columns[0]
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df.set_index(current_col,inplace=True)
    df.index.name = 'index'
    df.rename(columns={'index':current_col}, inplace=True)
    result = pd.concat([result,df],axis=1)
```

I then eventually get the output I am looking for with:

```
>>> result
>>> result.fillna(0)
```

But I would like to get these results to print to a txt file. I am currently running these commands in the terminal on a mac with python v3.7.4. I have tried opening a text file and writing the results to the text file with no success:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
file = open('counts.txt','w')
files = glob.glob('*.txt')
#eg: files = ['1.txt','2.txt']
result = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file,delimiter='  ')
    current_col = df.columns[0]
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df.set_index(current_col,inplace=True)
    df.index.name = 'index'
    df.rename(columns={'index':current_col}, inplace=True)
    result = pd.concat([result,df],axis=1)
file.write(result +'\n')
```

Comment: why not just use result.to_csv('counts.txt',sep=' ') or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

When you are done building `result`, just put it in a print statement like so:

```
print(result)
```

And then you can run your file like this:

```
$ python your_script.py >> /path/for_output_file.txt
```

It redirects all your print statements to the specified file.

If you use a single operator `>`, it will overwrite the results. So use `>>` to append.

Comment: what print statements

Comment: That was a general explanation of the redirection operator.

Comment: that is great..but running that command with this python file would do nothing

Comment: I see your point. My bad. Just edited my code to reflect that. Thanks!